# Entity Framework syntax confusion with DBset

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm currently following a C# tutorial, and it has this `ApplicationDbContext` class file:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext: DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) {}

    public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }   
}
```

Where `Category` is defined as:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Which is then later referenced like so:

```
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        Categories = _db.Category;
    }
```

I also have this code in the `Program.cs` file:

```
  builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
  options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
  ));
```

The final piece of info is that I did a migration to create a database table called `Category`.

My confusion is around how everything is declared here; the line in the `DbContext` file with `DbSet` doesn't seem to instantiate anything and instead just defines `Category` as a public variable with type `DbSet<Category>`, but then the `IEnumerable<Category>` seems to treat `Category` as if it's going through the table, as does calling `_db.Category`.

In this case, looking through the code, the `Category` class is what gets referenced and not the `Category` database table. How does everything tie together here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ApplicationDbContext` is just the *definition* of the data context. This effectively defines the *tables* in your database. Each `DbSet<T>` represents a table in your data schema.

- `DbContext` is the base class of this database schema definition.

`Category` is a data *Model*, on it's own, it is just another class that represents *something*... But when you use it in the `DbContext` via the `DbSet<Cateogry>` type it becomes a table definition. When you read this line:

```
public DbSet<CategoryType> CategoryName { get; set; }
```

Interpret it as this: `Table called CategoryName that the structure of the CategoryType class.`

So far so good,

This next bit is related to a concept called *[Dependency Injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0)*. the idea is that we can define at a global level a set of instructions that describe how  to instantiate objects that we need to use a lot throughout the application without putting that instantiation logic everywhere. It is a way to define this logic once and is inline with the [DRY principal](https://thevaluable.dev/dry-principle-cost-benefit-example/).

- You might think that the *contructor* of a class is an appropriate place for this type of information and before DI it was a common option, but for compex types this often requires a lot of external domain knowledge that is specific to the current application, which makes it hard to re-use your classes on other applications or contexts. DI is an elegant solution to this that forces you to totally divorce the definition of your types and the implementation.
- After contructors (and before DI), the next common implementation was to use the [Factory Pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern) to create objects using domain specific logic. Think of DI is a *specific* implementation of the *Factory Pattern*.

So in Program.cs, the following code is *registering* the `ApplicationDbContext` type for DI, using the `AddDbContext` *factory*.

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer(
  builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
));
```

- Part of this registration is to specify the connection string, in this case it is telling the underlying *factory* method to get the connection string from the configuration file.

The *magic* occurs now in the rest of your DI stack, in this case with your Razor Pages. The Razor Page Controller `IndexModel` is instantiated via DI, you will find this registration later in the Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

When the `IndexModel` PageModel controller is *needed*, DI will call the constructor on that class.

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext db) { ... }
}
```

As it requires an instance of `ApplicationDbContext` and DI *knows* how to create an instance of that type, it uses the `AddDbContext` factory to create a new instance of `ApplicationDbContext` and pass it through as an argument to the `IndexModel` constructor.

Comment: In regards to IndexModel, it's actually a razor page that inherits PageModel. I'm assuming then that builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); would be the dependency injection for razor pages, which then when IndexModel calls for an ApplicationDbContext object in its constructor that calls the DbContext injection?

Comment: That is correct! I'll update my post with a bit of clarity around that.

Answer (score 1):

> the line DbContext file with DbSet doesn't seem to instantiate anything and instead just defines Category as a public variable with type DbSet

Correct

> then the IEnumerable seems to treat Category as if it's going through the table

Also correct. the code in `Program.cs` ties the two together. First, it enables Dependency Injection of `_db` by calling `AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>()`; and second, it directs `_db` to retrieve data from the source (usually, database) defined in `DefaultConnection`. You should have this definition in `appsettings.json` - for example,

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=dbname;User ID=username;password=password;"
  }
}
```

Comment: So when is db as an object instantiated then? It seems like it's feeding an already existing object into IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext db)

Comment: @Dragnipur - the beauty of dependency injection is that you don't need to worry about it. It will be instantiated some time after you specified _how_ to instantiate it, and before you need it in your controller. My experience tells me that it is creating DB connection first time you need it - but it's buried in Entity Framework